# Are built-in Mathematica functions already parallelized?

Tags: parallelization

I've been noticing something strange since updating to Mathematica 8, and that is that occaisionally I'll see that the MathKernel is using up to 800% CPU in my Activity Monitor on OS X (I have 8 cores). I have no Parallel calls whatsoever, and this is in a single kernel, not across multiple kernels. My code is pretty much only Interpolates, Maps, Do loops, and plotting routines.

I'm curious if some of the built-in Mathematica routines are in fact already parallel, and if so, which ones?

Comment: occaisionally - As in: same function different cpu usage? Or does one function always give 800% cpu? I think the latter can be answered by mathematica users, the former might be independent of mathematica? or a Software bug somewhere

Comment: As a side question, why is `Sort` not multithreaded, are there not multithreaded implementations?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### Natively multi-threaded functions

A lot of functions are internally multi-threaded (image processing, numerical functions, etc.). For instance:

```
In[1]:= a = Image[RandomInteger[{0, 255}, {10000, 10000}], "Byte"];

In[2]:= SystemOptions["ParallelOptions"]

Out[2]= {"ParallelOptions" -> {"AbortPause" -> 2., "BusyWait" -> 0.01,
    "MathLinkTimeout" -> 15., "ParallelThreadNumber" -> 4, 
   "RecoveryMode" -> "ReQueue", "RelaunchFailedKernels" -> False}}

In[3]:= ImageResize[a, {3723, 3231}, 
   Resampling -> "Lanczos"]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[3]= {1.2428834, Null}

In[4]:= SetSystemOptions[
 "ParallelOptions" -> {"ParallelThreadNumber" -> 1}]

Out[4]= "ParallelOptions" -> {"AbortPause" -> 2., "BusyWait" -> 0.01, 
  "MathLinkTimeout" -> 15., "ParallelThreadNumber" -> 1, 
  "RecoveryMode" -> "ReQueue", "RelaunchFailedKernels" -> False}

In[5]:= ImageResize[a, {3723, 3231}, 
   Resampling -> "Lanczos"]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[5]= {2.7461943, Null}
```

### Functions calling optimized libraries

Mathematica surely gets benefit from multi-threaded libraries (such as MKL) too:

```
In[1]:= a = RandomReal[{1, 2}, {5000, 5000}];

In[2]:= b = RandomReal[1, {5000}];

In[3]:= SystemOptions["MKLThreads"]

Out[3]= {"MKLThreads" -> 4}

In[4]:= LinearSolve[a, b]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[4]= {4.9585104, Null}

In[5]:= SetSystemOptions["MKLThreads" -> 1]

Out[5]= "MKLThreads" -> 1

In[6]:= LinearSolve[a, b]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[6]= {8.5545926, Null}
```

Although, the same function may not get multi-threaded depending on the type of input.

### Compiled function

[`CompiledFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompiledFunction.html) and any other functions that automatically use [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compile.html) can be multi-threaded too, using [`Parallelization`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Parallelization.html) option to `Compile`.

### Caution

1. Measuring timing with `AbsoluteTiming` for multi-threaded functions could be inaccurate sometimes.
2. The performance gain is usually not direct proportion to the number of threads. It depends on a lot of different factors.
3. Increasing number of threads (by using `SetSystemOptions` ) more than what your CPU support (either physical or logical cores) is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the very informative answer. Is there any list available of the routines that are multi-threaded? The reason I ask is that if I do decide to use Parallel calls, having each processor execute 8 threads would result in 64 threads total, which I presume is much less efficient.

Comment: I am not aware of such a list, but I will post if I find one. Also, it depends on the situation. For instance `LinearSolve` doesn't get multi-threaded if it computes symbolically. And yes, `Parallel` call is less efficient for obvious reason, sometimes necessary.

Comment: You said, "Measuring timing with AbsoluteTiming for multi-threaded functions could be inaccurate sometimes.".  Do you mean by any change that `Timing` is inaccurate and `AbsoluteTiming` is accurate?  I thought `AbsoluteTiming` returned wall time, while `Timing` returned the sum of the amounts of time used by each core.  Or is this platform dependent?

Answer (score 8):

Some, yes. For example, many image processing functions are multi-threaded. One way to see whether a function is leveraging multi-threading is to perform the same kind of tests as for ImageResize in [Yu-Sung Chang's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3678/5). You will witness speed-up for dozens of functions, including for example (list really not exhaustive): `Binarize`, `Dilation`, `Erosion`, `ImageAdjust`, `ImageDeconvolve`, `MeanShiftFilter`, `MedianFilter`, `MorphologicalBranchPoints`, `MorphologicalGraph`, `Pruning`, `Radon`, `TotalVariationFilter`, `WienerFilter`, etc.

Comment: Can you give any data to back up this assertion? (I believe you, but data is needed.)

Comment: @rcollyer Fair enough... One way to see whether a function is leveraging multi-threading is to perform the same kind of tests as for ImageResize in Yu-Sung Chang's answer. You will witness speed-up for dozens of functions, including for example (list *really not* exhaustive): Binarize, Dilation, Erosion, ImageAdjust, ImageDeconvolve, MeanShiftFilter, MedianFilter, MorphologicalBranchPoints, MorphologicalGraph, Pruning, Radon, TotalVariationFilter, WienerFilter, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Some matrix operations seem to use more than one core. For instance,

```
Eigensystem[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2000, 2000}]]
```

uses two cores on my machine. This also works for sparse matrices:

```
ClearAll[tmparray];
tmparray = SparseArray[
   {
    {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] \[LessEqual] 2 \[Rule] RandomReal[]
    },
   {100000, 100000}
   ];

Eigenvalues[
 tmparray,
 -40
 ]
```

Probably this is done by the libraries that Mathematica calls.