# Whether NIntegrate evaluation is multithreaded or not?

Tags: numerical-integration, parallelization

About MultiThread evaluation I am talking about here, see this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26243/does-eigenvalues-evaluate-in-a-parallelized-way)

I am NIntegrate the function `grarm[e, 3, dimension, 1, 1, 0.005]`. There is matrix operation in function `grarm`, the `dimension` set the dim of the matrix.

I give the code of `gram` in the end.( **take notice that you will have to manually change the dimension to get different `gram` with different dimension variable before integration**)

OK, First I set `dimension` equals 7, and integrate the following

```
In:=NIntegrate[Im[grarm[e, 3, 7, 1, 1, 0.005]^2], {e, -0.3, 0}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 200] // AbsoluteTiming

Out:={7.454151, 0.0581345}
```

and If I use linux command `top` to monitor the cpu situation, I see it is single threaded. See
[image]

now, I set `dimension` to 9, and integrate the following

```
In[55]:= NIntegrate[Im[grarm[e, 3, 9, 1, 1, 0.005]^2], {e, -0.3, 0}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 200] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[55]= {83.592780, 0.0271489}
```

and If I use linux command `top` to monitor the cpu situation, I see it is multi-threaded. See
[image]

And Now I force the same integration to use one thread only, integrate the following

```
In[56]:= 
ParallelMap[
  NIntegrate[
    Im[grarm[e, #[[1]], 9, #[[2]], 1, 0.005]^2], {e, -0.3, 0}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 200] &, 
  Tuples[{Range[3, 3], Range[1, 1]}]] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[56]= {16.575363, {0.0271489}}
```

Notice it is much faster, that is odd.

In summary, There are two peculiar things waited to be explained

1. why dimension=7 is single thread while dimension=9 is multi-thread? Can `NIntegrate` actually naturally multi-threaded or not? Or the multi-thread is actually due to the matrix operation in the integrand(well, I personally think this is not likely)?
2. why multi-thread evaluation is much slower than single thread evaluation in the case of dimension 9?

---

In the end, the code for `grarm`.(don't forget to change the dimension, before integration)

```
dimension = 7;

Clear[armchairibbonmat]
armchairibbonmat[kx_, n_] :=
 (
  h = Table[0, {i, 1, 2 (n + 2)}, {j, 1, 2 (n + 2)}];
  a[m_] := 2 m - 1;
  b[m_] := 2 m;
  t1 = 1;
  aa = 1;
  Do[
   h[[b[i], a[i]]] = t1 E^(I kx aa);
   h[[a[i], b[i]]] = t1 E^(-I kx aa);
   h[[b[i + 1], a[i]]] = t1 E^(-I kx aa/2);
   h[[b[i - 1], a[i]]] = t1 E^(-I kx aa/2);
   h[[a[i - 1], b[i]]] = t1 E^(I kx aa/2);
   h[[a[i + 1], b[i]]] = t1 E^(I kx aa/2);
   , {i, 2, n + 1}];
  h = ArrayPad[h, -2]
  )

mat = Compile[{kx, n}, Evaluate@armchairibbonmat[kx, dimension]];
Clear[armchairibbonmat];
armchairibbonmat = mat;

Clear[gkarm]
gkarm[kx_?NumericQ, e_, xx_, width_, ii_, label_, \[Eta]_] := 
 Inverse[(e - I \[Eta]) IdentityMatrix[2*width] - 
    armchairibbonmat[kx, width]][[2*(ii - 1) + label, 
   2*(ii - 1) + label]]

Clear[fkx]
fkx[kx_?NumericQ, xx_] := E^(I kx xx)

Clear[grarm]
grarm[e_?NumericQ, xx_, width_, ii_, label_, \[Eta]_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  gkarm[kx, e, xx, width, ii, label, \[Eta]]*
   fkx[kx, xx], {kx, -\[Pi]/3, \[Pi]/3}, MaxRecursion -> 200]
```