# How to force an evaluation to use only one core?

Tags: evaluation, parallelization

There are some evaluations which are automatically parallelized or multithread if there are cores available.( for example, `Eigenvalues`)

But I don't want the evaluation to be automatically multithreaded, I want it to use only one core. How can I do it?

Comment: Notice that you can run 2 threads on one core too, only if you have multithreaded processor. But it is not the same thing as parallel computing.

Comment: @Kuba Yeah! I always noticed this. Sometimes, my parallel evaluations automatically became several 50% cpu running, If there are other people running their calculation on the same remote computer

Comment: Is there a list of which functions automatically multithread?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For `Eigenvalues` this will work:

```
SetSystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "ParallelThreadNumber" -> 1]
```

For functions which are using MKL libraries you can also use:

```
SetSystemOptions["MKLThreads" -> 1]
```

---

**Source**

- `"ParallelOptions"` are mentioned at the end of [tutorial / ParallelComputation / ParallelControls](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Compile/tutorial/Parallel.html)

It is wrriten there that you can reset it to the defaults by `"ParallelThreadNumber" -> $ProcessorCount`. But if you have cores that can be multithreaded then this number can be greater than `$ProcessorCount`.

- Somewhere in documentation center is example with "MKLThreads" (I know it from there) but I can't find it :) I appreciate link if someone knows it :).

Comment: MKL libraries? I don't have an idea about "MKL libraries". What is this?

Comment: [Math kernel library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_Kernel_Library) is used by for example `Solve`.

Comment: Its kind of an all in one math antibiotic for your Intel processor kernel ;)

Comment: @Kuba It seems that it is undocumented? If I set it to one, After I restart the  mathematica, can the value be back to one?

Comment: @Kuba I think you must familiar with multithread, can you take a look at this post (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31202/whether-nintegrate-evaluation-is-multithreaded-or-not) for me? Unfortunately, somebody down voted it

Comment: @Kuba Oh, `SetSystemOptions["MKLThreads" -> 1]` actually works for the `NIntegrate`. My fault. Thank you for your help! But I still wish you could look at the post I mentioned, there are peculiarities which I can't understand.

Comment: @matheorem I believe the standard way to set options like this as the default is using the `Kernel/init.m` file. See [(8221)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8221/121) and [(1874)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1874/121)

Comment: @matheorem I couldn;t find the second source but I will post it when I will. I saw your other question but I'm not competent enough to answer them :)

Comment: @Kuba after examing the answer for the second time. I found that set "ParallelThreadNumber" didn't work for `Eigenvalues`, set "MKL" works for it. You can check it. The "ParallelThreadNumber" setting works for image processing functions, see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3674/are-built-in-mathematica-functions-already-parallelized

Comment: @matheorem Try `Eigenvalues[
   SparseArray[{{x_, y_} /; Abs[x - y] < 3 -> 1}, {100, 100}]] // Timing // First` with 1 and 2 ParallelThreadNumber. It works for me.

Comment: @matheorem well, have you checked that?

Comment: @Kuba Oh, sorry. I have been away from here a couple of days. I tried your code. Yeah, it works. But if you change 1->1.0, that is try `Eigenvalues[ SparseArray[{{x_, y_} /; Abs[x - y] < 3 -> 1.0}, {100, 100}]] // Timing // First` you will see it multithread again. I don't know why. That is odd.

Comment: @matheorem Interesting :) I will check that later.