# Mathematica, MKL_NUM_THREADS, and GNU/Linux Process Limits

Tags: linux, crash, mkl

I am using *Mathematica* 10.3 on a large GNU/Linux system (CentOS 6.6) with 40 processors and 250 GB of RAM.  It is a delight to watch it chew through linear algebra problems using all the processors.

However, it seems that the system becomes unstable, and perhaps even the Mathematica Kernel crashes, after evaluating expressions that use all of these resources. (A built-in example is to evaluate the `NDEigensystem` help notebook on the 40-core machine.) It seems as though the system has run out of permissible user processes.

When I issue (zsh):

```
 ~> limit

 cputime         unlimited
 filesize        unlimited
 datasize        unlimited
 stacksize       10MB
 coredumpsize    0kB
 memoryuse       unlimited
 maxproc         1024
 descriptors     1024
 memorylocked    64kB
 addressspace    unlimited
 maxfilelocks    unlimited
 sigpending      256546
 msgqueue        819200
 nice            0
 rt_priority     0
```

which leads me to believe that as many settings as are relevant are `unlimited`.

I have also explored various settings for `OMP_NUM_THREADS` and `MKL_NUM_THREADS`--setting these to smaller settings, e.g. `MKL_NUM_THREADS=8`, does not seem to exhibit the instability.  However, the other cores remain unused, and these really need to be in play for Mathematica to remain competitive with other technologies such as R linked with MKL.

There are other settings for OMP and MKL, such as `OMP_DYNAMIC`, but I have not found a magic recipe to get this to work.

My question: have other users seen such (mis)behavior, and are there settings that can be invoked in order to get around these issues?

Comment: I think `maxproc` counts each thread in every process separately, so 1024 may not be enough. Is there any difference if you set it to unlimited?

Comment: Can you let me know which example of the `NDEigensystem` page crashes for you? How many threads can you use until you see the crash?

Comment: @ilian i think this may be the solution, thanks!  i'm going to test this for a bit and then write back.