# How to numerically solve a 1-d time-independent Schrödinger equation?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, physics

The point is to solve the eigensystem of the given Hamiltonian.

I tried `ParametricNDSolve` combined with `FindRoot` to search for eigenvalues as xslittlegrass did in his post [Find eigen energies of time-independent Schrödinger equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32293) in the first place. It gave almost perfect results,but then I found it very inconvenient for large amounts of eigenstate as xslittlegrass did.

Apparently some of the methods used in xslittlegrass's post won't work here directly. My potential is not a polynomial. I'm trying to adjust their methods but so far no luck.

I tried different approaches, including using the radial wavefunction of hydrogen atom as basis and change the Hamiltonian into a matrix, using finite difference method to convert it into a eigenvalue problem and so on. I then found out the new version of *Mathematica* added a new function called `NDEigensystem`.

I tried those all and the outcome was just far away from what I expected. The closest one was the radial wavefunction of hydrogen atom, and it had about 10% error. The others didn't give me a proper result, not even close. As for `NDEigensystem`, I don't know how to apply a Neumann condition to it. For harmonic oscillator, `NDEigensystem` seems fine, but when I applied it to Coulomb potential, the results were terribly wrong. I supposed it's because of the improper boundary, I only attached a `DirichletCondition` to it. But I couldn't add a Neumann condition.

Here's some details (**with Jens' help, I've been able to apply `NDEigensystem` to this, and I'm very grateful for that**):

My potential is:

```
V[r_] = -(1/r) - (1.0415223038416566` E^(-0.9990999998788636` r))/r
```

1. Using the radial function of hydrogen atom, I wrote the following code:

   ```
   a = 1; l = 0; nmax = 20;
   R[n_, r_] = FullSimplify[
      2/(a^(3/2) n^2 (2 l + 1)!) Sqrt[(n + l)!/(n - l - 1)!]
       E^(-1/2 (2 r)/(n a)) ((2 r)/(n a))^l 
         Hypergeometric1F1[-n + l + 1, 2 l + 2, (2 r)/(n a)]]
   u[n_, r_] = r R[n, r]
   HMax = ParallelTable[NIntegrate[u[n, r] (-α^-1 \!\(
     \*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(r, r\)]\((u[i, r])\)\) + 
      V[r] u[i, r]), {r, 0, ∞}, 
      AccuracyGoal -> ∞, WorkingPrecision -> 30, 
      PrecisionGoal -> 6], {n, 1, nmax}, {i, 1, nmax}];
   N[Eigenvalues[HMax], 6]
   ```

   And the results:

   > $$ \small\begin{array}{lllll}\{&-1.00113,& -0.15272,& -0.0619985, &-0.0336547, &-0.0211352,\\
   >  &-0.0145071,& -0.0105749,& -0.00805096,& -0.00633443, &-0.00511407,\\
   > &-0.00421542, &-0.00353452,& -0.00300626,& -0.00258818, &-0.00225162,\\
   > &-0.00197665, &-0.0017491, &-0.00155863, &-0.00139753,& -0.00125987\quad\}\end{array}$$

   The results,as mentioned above,were not so good.
2. This is the code using `NDEigensystem` as Jens showed (I'm only interested in eigenvalues,so I replaced `NDEigensystem` with `NDEigenvalues`, and I modified it a little to increase accuracy):

   ```
   AbsoluteTiming[
    With[{shift = 10, d = 500, n = 20}, 
     ev = NDEigenvalues[{shift f[r] + V[r] f[r] - 
        1/2 f''[r](*+NeumannValue[0,r\[Equal]d]*), 
        DirichletCondition[f[r] == 0, True]}, f[r], {r, 0, d}, n, 
        Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
        {"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}}, 
        "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", MaxIterations -> Infinity}}];
     evShifted = ev - shift]]
   ```

   It took me `2540.17s` to complete the calculation.

   > $$\small\begin{array}{lllll}\{&-1.33732, &-0.186434, &-0.0710575,& -0.0374072, &-0.023051, \\&-0.0156184, &-0.0112778, &-0.00852433, &-0.00666881, &-0.00535929,\\ &-0.0044008, 
   > &-0.00367822, &-0.00312003, &-0.00267982,& -0.0023228,\\ &-0.00199518, 
   > &-0.00162513, &-0.0011884, &-0.000689036,& -0.000132268\quad\}\end{array}$$

   As I mentioned in the comments,in low energy levels, the results are good,but when it comes to higher levels, the accuracy drops rapidly. The accuracy only increased with `d` and `MaxCellMeasure`, and the code becomes less efficient in the meantime.

   Oh, BTW, a `MaxCellMeasure` up to `0.001` could be unnecessary. When I change it to `0.01`, and increase `b` to `1000`, I spent `1511.33s` and have a much better result. For error tolerance only at 10E-7, I suppose bigger `MaxCellMeasure` would be better.

And **here's the binding energy I obtained from the `NDSolve` & `FindRoot` approach**

> $$\small\begin{array}{cccc}
> n  & \text{energy}      & n   & \text{energy}  \\
> 1S & 1.33732     & 6S  & 0.0156184 \\
> 2S & 0.186434    & \dots &   \\
> 3S & 0.0710575   & 10S & 0.00535929  \\
> 4S & 0.0374072   & 20S & 0.0012937 \\
> 5S & 0.023051\end{array}$$

It's very kind of Jens to modify this table for me, which was so crude in the first place. The eigenvalue should be like that, but in low energy states, my results are far from what it should be. I don't know where this error is coming from, and if there is a better way to do this.

If this problem can be fixed, I'd be very grateful for that.

**Solving Coulomb Potential using Jens' variable substitution method**

I'm going to save myself some trouble, just post my code and result here:

code which is basically copy from Jens':

```
V[r_] = -14.3996448504451555789912633575295935414`6.88249108029756/r;
α = 0.26246843532124502683678435500618410715`6.076375074285658;

radialEq = V[r] f[r] - f''[r]/α;
radialξ = 
   Simplify[radialEq /. f -> (ψ[ArcTan[#]] &) /. r -> (Tan[ξ]),
      Pi/2 > ξ > 0]

With[{max = 20, shift = 10}, {ev, ef} = 
 NDEigensystem[{radialξ + shift ψ[ξ], 
   DirichletCondition[ψ[ξ] == 0, 
   True]}, ψ[ξ], {ξ, 0, Pi/2}, max, 
   Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
   {"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}}, 
   "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", MaxIterations -> 40000}}];
 evNew = ev - shift]
```

And results:

> $$\small\begin{array}{lllll}  
> &-13.6057,& -3.40142,& -1.51174, &-0.850356,& -0.544228, \\&-0.377936, 
>    & -0.277667, &-0.212588, &-0.167969, &-0.13605,\\& -0.112427, &-0.0944449, \
>   &  -0.0804237, &-0.0692623, &-0.0601369, \\&-0.0524875, &-0.0468007, \
>    & -0.0402104, &-0.0350137, &-0.0310644\end{array}$$

And the real energy:

```
Ehydrogen = 
 Table[-QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Rydbergs"], "eV"]]/
   n^2, {n, 20}]
```

> $$\small\begin{array}{lllll}&-13.60569,& -3.401423, &-1.511744, &-0.850356, &-0.5442277, \\&-0.3779359, \
> &-0.2776672, &-0.2125889,& -0.1679715, &-0.1360569,\\& -0.1124437, \
> &-0.0944840, &-0.0805071, &-0.06941680,& -0.06046974, \\&-0.05314724, \
> &-0.04707852, &-0.04199288, &-0.03768890, &-0.03401423\end{array}$$

The error:

> $$\small\begin{array}{lllll}&-2.72446*10^{-8}, &-6.8044*10^{-9}, &-2.97381*10^{-9}, &-7.99033*10^{-10}, &
>   6.76493*10^{-9},\\& 4.52332*10^{-8}, &2.05556*10^{-7}, &7.58432*10^{-7}, 
> & 2.39862*10^{-6}, 
>  &6.70562*10^{-6}, \\&0.0000169127, &0.0000390625, &0.0000833608, \
>    &  0.000154477,& 0.000332808,\\& 0.000659734,& 0.00027787,& 0.00178247, \
> & 0.00267516,& 0.00294987\end{array}$$

When I increase the `MaxCellMeasure` to 0.0001, the error decrease a lot:

> $$\small\begin{array}{lllll}&-2.75312*10^{-8}, &-6.81183*10^{-9}, &-3.03523*10^{-9}, &-1.70471*10^{-9}, \
> &-1.08962*10^{-9}, \\&-7.52408*10^{-10}, &-5.35404*10^{-10}, &-3.49364*10^{-10}, \
> &-9.34864*10^{-11},& 4.12964*10^{-10}, \\&1.53102*10^{-9}, &3.96303*10^{-9}, \
> &9.01172*10^{-9},& 1.89823*10^{-8}, &3.77832*10^{-8}, \\&7.17968*10^{-8}, \
> &1.31103*10^{-7},& 2.31154*10^{-7}, &3.9495*10^{-7},& 6.58026*10^{-7}\end{array}$$

Comment: You might find this useful: [Solving the Schroedinger equation for bound states with Mathematica 3.0](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9811453v2) (arXiv link).

Comment: Your code doesn't run because `Alpha` is undefined. Where did you get the values in the last table?

Comment: I was initially confused about your use of Neumann boundary conditions. I think you must mean something else, because by comparing with your desired eigenvalues I concluded that you're really solving the radial equation for the reduced wave function, where no Neumann boundary condition is needed. The biggest problem is how to deal with the conditions of vanishing amplitude at infinity.

Comment: SORRY,my bad,`alpha` is a pre-defined value,actually it's the schroedinger constant.Here it's value is `2.`.I'm terribly sorry that you have to find out this on your own.And thank you very much for your tutorial in `NDEigensystem`.

Comment: @Jens OMG, there are Goto[]s in that Arxiv paper's code!!! For a moment I thought I was reading a BASIC program.

Comment: @Peltio I know, it's really funny... who said that reading scientific articles can't be amusing? And it shows why sites like this are needed.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Why the original matrix approach fails

The question originally showed an attempt at a solution based on converting the differential operator (the Hamiltonian) into a matrix (`HMax`) by forming a `Table` of overlap integrals. The functions used in these integrals were the bound-state eigenfunctions of the hydrogen radial equation. Although the matrix obtained in this way has eigenvalues that converge quickly, the convergence is not to the expected eigenvalues of the potential `V[r]` (which differs from that of the hydrogen atom).

The reason why this approach doesn't work is that the **bound states** of hydrogen alone do *not* form a complete set in which an arbitrary radial wave function can be expanded. What's missing is the uncountably infinite set of *positive-energy* solutions to the hydrogen radial equation. Their form is in fact given on *Mathematica*'s help page for [`Hypergeometric1F1`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric1F1.html), under "Applications." These  functions have to be included when considering matrix elements of an arbitrary radial operator. However, since they form a continuum, they don't lend themselves to the construction of a simple matrix as was intended in the question.

The conclusion is that we cannot expect the original approach in the question to work on physical grounds. The numerical approach based on finite-element discretization discussed below circumvents this problem to a certain extent. However, the presence of a continuum in the spectrum indirectly causes trouble in the `NDEigensystem` calculations, too, because the bound states we're after crowd together in a dense sequence of eigenvalues near the ionization threshold at zero eigenvalue, if you seek progressively larger number of radial nodes.

To salvage the above method of constructing a finite matrix, one should choose a different basis in which to expand the Hamiltonian. For example, the harmonic oscillator in 3D gives you a complete set of radial functions with a purely discrete spectrum that could be used instead of the hydrogenic solutions. Of course, this then becomes more of a physics problem, not a *Mathematica* issue.

### Using `NDEigensystem`

The question mentions that you didn't know how to use `NDEigensystem` because of the boundary conditions. So I'll try to address the calculation with this approach. You can in fact use `NDEigensystem` for this problem, as long as the states of interest fit well into the simulation domain. Here is something that works for the lowest states. It imposes `DirichletCondition` at *both ends*. The reduced radial wave function should indeed vanish for $r=0$, too. This is because it's divided by `r` when forming the 3D wave function, and there can't be a divergence in that function.

Below, I'll choose $\alpha=2$ because it gives agreement with the eigenvalues you were expecting (except for the sign, which I'm pretty sure is simply omitted in the question):

```
V[r_] = -(1/r) - (1.0415223038416566` E^(-0.9990999998788636` r))/r

With[{shift = 10, d = 30, n = 5}, {ev, ef} = 
  NDEigensystem[{shift f[r] + V[r] f[r] - 1/2 f''[r],
     DirichletCondition[f[r] == 0, True]}, f[r], {r, 0, d}, n, 
   Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}}, 
     "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi"}}];
 evShifted = ev - shift]
```

> `{-1.33732, -0.186434, -0.0710474, -0.0348373, -0.00119517}`

```
With[{n = 4, d = 30, amplitudes = {-1, 5, 20, 30}},
 Plot[Evaluate[
   Table[evShifted[[i]] + amplitudes[[i]] 1/r ef[[i]], {i, n}]], {r, 
   0, d}, PlotRange -> {-4, 4}, 
  Epilog -> {Gray, Dashed, 
    Table[Line[{{0, evShifted[[i]]}, {d, evShifted[[i]]}}], {i, n}]}]]
```

[image: waves]

Here I plotted the wave functions of the first four states (divided by `r` because that's how your `f[r]` is related to the true 3D radial wave function). The functions are offset by their eigenvalues. Looking at the list of eigenvalues above, you can also see that the agreement with the values listed in the question is good, for the first three states.

The fourth wave function with the largest number of nodes is seen to extend all the way to the boundary where I applied the `DirichletCondition`. This causes numerical deviations from the true eigenvalue of the infinite domain for all states higher than the third one. You can fix this by increasing the domain and changing `MaxCellMeasure`.

In order to get the eigenvalues to come out sorted the right way, I manually added a `shift` to the potential such that all eigenvalues are positive. Then I subtract that shift again at the end. It's supposed to be possible to specify the same method for the eigensolver with the `Arnoldi` method, but I found that adding the method option `"Arnoldi ", "Shift" -> -10` while setting my manual `shift` to zero, the eigenvalues are sorted the wrong way around for our purposes of getting the spectrum starting with the ground state (so it's mainly a matter of taste whether to use that option or not).

**Edit more efficient calculation**

Using `NDEigensystem` on the given radial equation is made difficult by the fact that the integration domain extends from zero to positive infinity. Since the solver is based on a finite-element discretization, I decided to reformulate the problem using a transformation of variables that maps the radial coordinate `r` onto a finite interval: $r\equiv \tan\xi$ where $\xi \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. This produces accurate results **much faster** than the more straightforward approach above.

First, Let's do the substitution of variables in the radial equation (assuming `V` is defined as above):

```
Clear[f,r,ξ,ψ];
radialEq = V[r] f[r] - f''[r]/2;

radialξ = 
 Simplify[radialEq /. f -> (ψ[ArcTan[#]] &) /. 
   r -> (Tan[ξ]), Pi/2 > ξ > 0]
```

> $$-\frac{1}{2} \cos ^4(\xi ) \psi ''(\xi )+\sin (\xi ) \cos
>    ^3(\xi ) \psi '(\xi )+\psi (\xi ) \left(-1.04152
>    e^{-0.9991 \tan (\xi )}-1\right) \cot (\xi )$$

This is now the equation to be solved, and the rest proceeds as before (again I use only Dirichlet boundary conditions at both ends):

```
With[{max = 20, shift = 10}, {ev, ef} = 
  NDEigensystem[{radialξ + shift ψ[ξ], 
    DirichletCondition[ψ[ξ] == 0, True]}, ψ[ξ], {ξ, 0, Pi/2}, max, 
    Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
     {"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}}, 
      "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", MaxIterations -> 40000}}];
 evNew = ev - shift]
```

> $$\begin{array}{cccc}
>  -1.33732 & -0.186434 & -0.0710575 & -0.0374072 \\
>  -0.023051 & -0.0156184 & -0.0112777 & -0.0085241 \\
>  -0.00666806 & -0.00535715 & -0.00439514 & -0.00366612 \\
>  -0.00310643 & -0.00260488 & -0.00223437 & -0.00192196 \\
>  -0.00162614 & -0.0014017 & -0.000978152 & -0.000545353 \\
> \end{array}$$

The agreement with the last results listed in the question (using `NDEigenvalues` with large domain) seems to be very good, but the speed is orders of magnitude faster with the transformation of variables as done here.

**Edit: comparison to hydrogenic wave functions**

The hydrogen atom is a good test case because it exhibits the same divergence at the origin as the potential in the question, and also is very long-range so that the trick of transforming the independent variable is equally useful here. The exact solutions are known, and I define them below as `u` for the special case of zero angular momentum (that's what the radial equation in the question refers to).

Then I repeat the numerical solution for the Coulomb potential and plot a comparison of the solutions with the exact results in a single panel for all solutions:

```
Clear[u]; 
u[n_][r_] := 
 r (2 E^(-(r/n)) Sqrt[(-1 + n)!/n!] LaguerreL[-1 + n, 1, (2 r)/n])/n^2

Clear[f, r, ξ, ψ];
V[r_] := -1/r;
radialEq = V[r] f[r] - f''[r]/2;
radialξ = 
 Simplify[radialEq /. f -> (ψ[ArcTan[#]] &) /. r -> (Tan[ξ]),
   Pi/2 > ξ > 0]
```

> $$ -\frac{1}{2} \cos ^4(\xi ) \psi ''(\xi )+\sin (\xi ) \cos
>    ^3(\xi ) \psi '(\xi )-\psi (\xi ) \cot (\xi )$$

This is the equation to be solved next. Note that I ask for the solutions to be returned as bare `InterpolationFunction` objects by omitting the argument of `ψ[ξ]` in the second slot of  `NDEigensystem`. This makes the subsequent manipulations easier. Other than that, I used the same settings as in the previous calculation.

```
With[{max = 20, shift = 10}, {ev, ef} = 
   NDEigensystem[{radialξ + shift ψ[ξ], 
     DirichletCondition[ψ[ξ] == 0, True]}, ψ, {ξ, 0,
      Pi/2}, max, 
    Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}}, 
      "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", MaxIterations -> 40000}}];
  evNew = ev - shift];

Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]

amplitudes = 
  Table[NLimit[u[i][r]/ef[[i]][ArcTan[r]], r -> 0], {i, Length[ef]}];

GraphicsGrid@
 Partition[
  Table[Plot[{amplitudes[[i]] ef[[i]][ArcTan[r]], u[i][r]}, {r, 0, 
     30}, Frame -> None, Axes -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Directive[Black, Dashing[.1]]}], {i, 
    Length[ef]}], 4]
```

[image: comparison]

The two plots lie on top of each other for all 20 states.

To make the comparison, I had to find the proper amplitude factors that make the graphs equal at some point. I chose to do that by calculating the ratio between numerical and exact solution in the limit $r\to 0$ using `NLimit`. This limit always exists even though both functions vanish there.

The *eigenvalues* cluster together around zero for higher node numbers, and therefore a constant *absolute* error translates into a much larger *relative* error. This can only be fixed by increasing the spatial resolution. For the (low) resolution that I chose in the above calculation, the eigenvalues are only useful up to roughly the tenth solution:

```
evNew[[;; 14]]
```

> $$\begin{array}{cccc}
>  -0.5 & -0.125 & -0.0555556 & -0.03125 \\
>  -0.02 & -0.0138889 & -0.010204 & -0.00781215 \\
>  -0.00617175 & -0.00499706 & -0.00412515 & -0.0034518 \\
>  -0.00293943 & -0.00250752 & \text{} & \text{} \\
> \end{array}$$

```
-0.5/Range[14]^2
```

> $$\begin{array}{cccc}
>  -0.5 & -0.125 & -0.0555556 & -0.03125 \\
>  -0.02 & -0.0138889 & -0.0102041 & -0.0078125 \\
>  -0.00617284 & -0.005 & -0.00413223 & -0.00347222 \\
>  -0.00295858 & -0.00255102 & \text{} & \text{} \\
> \end{array}$$

The last line shows the expected exact results.

Comment: Thank you so much.So my problem is with the `shift`.In your code,without a `shift`,the eigenvalues are just like what I solved before,with little difference.BUT why do I need a `shift`?You said "sort" the eigenvalues,I don't know if I'm getting this right,is it because there are lots of redundant eigenvalues and the program needs to sort them and put the biggest as well as the most accurate ones ahead?And what if we use methods other than `"Arnoldi"`?

Comment: And about the accuracy,it seems decreased with higher energy level?The first few are nearly perfect for me,then it just goes very wrong.What do you think if we add `f'[d]==-10^-6` as a boundary condition?The function would converge faster,I think.And this is what I need a Neumann condition for.

Comment: The closer to the "ionization threshold" you get, the larger the true wave functions are. I don't think any simple boundary condition can fix the resulting errors, unless the domain is made larger (which eventually makes `NDEigensystem` run out of time or memory). Arnoldi is (I believe) the default method, I just added it explicitly so that I can also try out different sub-methods (such as `"Shift"). With or without shift, you should of course get the same eigenvalues, but sorted differently. But different sorting (default is absolute value) means the ground state comes much later in the list.

Comment: Nice answer! +1

Comment: @user21 Standing on the shoulders of giants...

Comment: I think I am going to print that one out - for bad days... Thanks. No, seriously if you have something I should look at concerning NDEigensystem, please let me know. Ideas for improvement, comments etc...

Comment: BTW,is there any way to parallelize this procedure?

Comment: Parallelization already [happens internally](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55914/245), but as you can see in my updated answer, a huge speedup is possible just using the parallel processor also known as "brain"... I checked this transformation of variables for the pure Coulomb problem, too, and it works there as well.

Comment: I post my results of Coulomb problem above.Why it requires much more condensed grid,I mean,a smaller MaxCellMeasure to reach the accuracy which I can easily get without this transformation(though costs more time)?And what do you mean by "brain"(the parallel processor you mentioned)?I'm sorry but I didn't see it anywhere in your updated answer.

Comment: The higher the excitation, the more nodes the wavefunction has. These are now squeezed into a fixed interval, so you need increased spatial resolution to reduce the error for high-lying states. Ignore the "brain" remark, it was a joke about something I don't use very often (but biologists claim everybody has one - it's just a theory, though).

Comment: Oh!I thought you mean something like neural network or similar stuff,and I got it all wrong...But thanks,it's really helpful.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again,but I was checking the wavefunction of the Coulomb problem(comparing it to the analytic solution),and found your variable substisution method has relatively lower accuracy in eigenvectors,and 3rd,4st ones are not even close.Would you please check if my calculation went wrong?

Comment: You must have made a mistake. I tested it and found excellent agreement. I'll add the comparison soon.

Comment: I forgot to normalize it...That was sloppy.Sorry.But you were just using the analytic solution to normalize it if I'm getting this right?What if I arbitrary choose one point and do your amplitude thing?I tried and the curve fitted well.So what's the difference then?And what if I use NIntegrate to normalize it?There might be a little sign problem but that's ok I think?

Comment: I just used the $r\to 0$ limit because at random other points you could accidentally get a divide-by-zero error when doing the normalization the way I did. Integrating to normalize seems way too costly for simple comparisons, but it's certainly an option. The eigenfunctions near zero energy do become very oscillatory in the transformed variable, so both `NDEigensystem` and `NIntegrate` will need a lot of points to get things right.

Comment: But for some potential we don't have a analytic solution,I would have to use NIntegrate.Do you have any better options?And,this might be a little off the topic,but how do you deal with integration in high energy level normalization?When I tried it,I couldn't converge from 0 to infinity(that happens when `n=6` and higher).

Comment: If you don't have analytic comparison functions, then there is nothing to compare to, right? So there's nothing to do, since the eigenfunctions in `NDEigensystem` are already normalized by default. If you're asking about something else, it's better to start a new question.

Comment: But you're using variable transformation,and once you transform variable back to `r` ,you'll have to normalize it again.In the previous automatic normalization,I believe the integrand should have an extra `Sec[\[theta]]^2` to match `r`'s normalization.

Comment: I think it's easiest to do that kind of normalization with an $r$ integral directly, then you won't need any Jacobian factors. But of course you'll get problems when the high-lying states aren't spatially resolved, as I already said. If you want such states to be represented more accurately, you'll have to modify either `MaxCellMeasure` or the transformation of variables. Maybe I'll write some more tomorrow.

Comment: Jens, if have the time could you have a look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110367/18437) answer and tell me if it seems correct to you. That would be great. Thanks.