# Schrödinger equation for Hydrogen atom

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I'm trying to solve **Schrödinger 1D equation for hydrogen atom** but I found several difficulties.

To get in context I want to solve this equation

[image]

For Z and l real and arbitraries.
To start with I tried for Z=1 and l=0
and I tried in the following way

```
    Z = 1
    l = 0
    U[x_] := -Z/x - l (l + 1)/(2 x ^2)
    {RM} = Solve[U[x] == Ei && x > 0 && Ei < 0, x, Reals][[All, 1, -1]]

    (*What I'm going to do is to find for wich x the potential energy U[x] 
     is equal to the eigenenergy Ei. 
     Then I'll solve only in the interval {0,RM} and Ei will be a parameter*)
```

So far now I only defined the things I'm going to use, Now I'll solve from 0 to RM and as boundary conditions given by the Oppenheimer conditions that says

[image]

So I can set the wave function at (r=0) to any arbitrary value, say 2 and then I have the other condition on the derivative. Then the normalization factor will fix to the correct value.

What I did next was to use `ParametricNDSolveValue`

```
    SCHR1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{-1/2 \[Psi]''[x] + U[x] \[Psi][x] == 
Ei \[Psi][x], \[Psi][.0001] == 
2., \[Psi]'[.0001] == -2}, \[Psi], {x, .0001, RM}, {Ei}]
```

Now I'll solve for RM to infinity (I mean far away, like 10RM would be ok), with continuity as contour condition and in infinity the function has to be zero

```
    SCHR2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{-1/2 f''[x] + U[x] f[x] == Ei f[x],

    f[RM] == SCHR1[Ei][RM], f[10 RM] == 0}, f, {x, RM, 10 RM}, {Ei}]
```

This actually solves something, but not the something I want and it hasn't
even the correct shape.

I hope I'd be clear.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105298/how-to-numerically-solve-a-1-d-time-independent-schrodinger-equation)

Comment: Your solution approach seems overly complicated because it still requires matching the derivatives at $RM$ after already having introduced the (not strictly valid) condition of vanishing amplitude at $10RM$. You may as well do just a single `ParametricNDSolveValue` up to $10RM$ and solve for the `Ei` that makes the amplitude vanish at the end point. Then the continuity of the function and its derivative is automatically insured. Also, `SCHR2` didn't solve anything when I tried it.

Comment: Yes, still needs to match the derivates at that point. I tried on this way because using one  `ParametricNDSolveValue`  didn't solve de Schrödinger equation, because it has the wrong energies and I had a solution for every energy (even if it was the wrong energry). I hoped solving on this way to force all those solution to be only one