# Finite Element Parallel NDSolve

Tags: parallelization, finite-element-method

How can `"MeshElementBlocks"` be used with `NDSolve` to run a parallel kernel evaluation of a Finite Element problem?

```
Ω = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {100, 100}], Rectangle[{40, 40}, {60, 60}]];

fea[grid_, goal_, blocks_: 1] := {"FiniteElement",
  "MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> grid}, 
    AccuracyGoal -> goal, PrecisionGoal -> goal, 
    "MeshElementBlocks" -> blocks}}

sol = Parallelize[NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 100., 
    x == 40 && 40 <= y <= 60 || x == 60 && 40 <= y <= 60 || 
     40 <= x <= 60 && y == 40 || 40 <= x <= 60 && y == 60], 
   u[x, 0] == u[x, 100] == u[0, y] == u[100, y] == 0},
  u, {x, y} ∈ Ω, Method -> fea[1, 8, 4]]]
```

Reference:

[Partial Differential Equation in Parallel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55914/partial-differential-equation-in-parallel/96363#comment335566_96363)

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/176979/18437). Hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is part of a different approach. This leads in essence to a domain decomposition. One can use the Options `"PartialSystemMatricesAssembly"` of `DiscretizePDE`. This example is from the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/DiscretizePDE.html).

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
nr = ToNumericalRegion[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1/2}]];
vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables", 
     "Space"} -> {{u}, {x, y}}];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space"} -> {nr}];
cdata = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd, 
   "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{-IdentityMatrix[2]}}];
mdata2 = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"MeshElementBlocks" -> 5}}];
mdata2["ElementMesh"]
```

Partially discretize a PDE with blocks numbers 1, 2, and 5 :

```
dpde1 = 
 DiscretizePDE[cdata, mdata2, sd, 
  "PartialSystemMatricesAssembly" -> {1, 2, 5}]
```

Extract and visualize the assembled stiffness matrix :

```
MatrixPlot[dpde1["StiffnessMatrix"]]
```

[image]

Partially discretize a PDE with blocks numbers 3 and 4 :

```
dpde2 = DiscretizePDE[cdata, mdata2, sd, 
  "PartialSystemMatricesAssembly" -> {3, 4}]
```

Extract and visualize the assembled stiffness matrix :

```
MatrixPlot[dpde2["StiffnessMatrix"]]
```

[image]

Discretize a PDE over all mesh elements:

```
dpde = DiscretizePDE[cdata, mdata2, sd]
```

Verify that the sum of the partially assembled system matrices is \
equal to the system matrices assembled as a whole :

```
dpde["StiffnessMatrix"] == 
   dpde1["StiffnessMatrix"] + dpde2["StiffnessMatrix"]
True
```

Now, in a next step one would solve over the partially assembled system matrices and then construct the solution from that. I don't have code for that. Here is an example from the MATLAB PDE toolbox that does something like [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/examples/poisson-s-equation-using-domain-decomposition.html), perhaps that's useful.

Comment: @Young, if you do figure this out. I'd be very interested in hearing about that. Good luck.

Comment: I've made some progress on this but need more free time to compete ... thank you for the bounty on the other question!

Comment: @Young, if you figure this one out there will be another one ;-)

Comment: @Young did you get a chance to look at this in more detail?

Answer (score 3):

For using "MeshElementBlocks" there is an example for that in the [Finite Element Programming tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html) but I am not sure this is what you are looking for. The "MeshElementBlocks" are for lowering the memory consumption and/or for doing something called domain decomposition. While domain decomposition is essentially for solving FEM models in parallel I do not have an example for that.

When you run this

```
Ω = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {100, 100}], Rectangle[{40, 40}, {60, 60}]];

sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 100., 
    x == 40 && 40 <= y <= 60 || x == 60 && 40 <= y <= 60 || 
     40 <= x <= 60 && y == 40 || 40 <= x <= 60 && y == 60], 
   u[x, 0] == u[x, 100] == u[0, y] == u[100, y] == 0}, 
  u, {x, y} ∈ Ω, 
  Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.05}}]
```

you will see that some parts (the FEM element computation and the LinearSolve) will run in parallel if you look at, for example, top on Linux.

Comment: So when using blocks, the `MaxMemoryUsed[]` should be lower?

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that. Have a look at the section about solving memory intensive PDEs in the [Finite Element best practice tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html)

Comment: Any chance of seeing an example of how to use blocks to parallelize a NDSolve FE problem?

Comment: @Young not in the immediate future. I'd like to focus on something else before that. Sorry about that.

Comment: I understand. Can you just tell me how to break this `ElementMesh[{{-0.0365, 0.0365}, {-0.0365, 0.0365}}, {TriangleElement[
   "<" 36134 ">"], TriangleElement["<" 36134 ">"], 
  TriangleElement["<" 36134 ">"], TriangleElement["<" 36134 ">"]}]` into the 4 separate block regions so I can solve them independently?