# Whether Parallel computing or Gpu Computing can be performed for mathematica built-in functions?

Tags: parallelization, gpu

I want to know how to run my mathematica code using GPU or parallel computing without any special coding besides using the original Mathematica code.

Comment: Read https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3674/are-built-in-mathematica-functions-already-parallelized, that should get you started, and provide some pointers for further research.

Comment: "without any special coding" No way.

Comment: Question is too broad. What in particular are you attempting to run in parallel or shift to the GPU?