# Is FindMinimum function multithreaded? Is it worth it to use this function in ParallelDo loop?

Tags: functions, parallelization

I have to call FindMinimum function n times on my data.

But when I put it in ParallelDo loop it works slower than in casual Do loop.

I wonder what might be the case (in the loop there are no other time-consuming functions).

I have 8-core CPU so I thought that ParallelDo should calculate things much faster.

EDIT: I noticed that finest grained is calculating way slower than Automatic. So for now somehow Do > ParallelDo(automatic) > ParallelDo[finest grained] but I don't understand why :(

Comment: These two answers (and others) help to explain questions about multi-threading and parallelization: [Natively multi-threaded functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3674/are-built-in-mathematica-functions-already-parallelized/3678#3678), and [A general guide to parallelization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48295/why-wont-parallelize-speed-up-my-code/48296#48296).